# Adding a click event to Zynga's new Canvas Scrolling API

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll

In case you missed it on HN, Zynga open sourced a great tiling / scrolling API for Canvas.

https://github.com/zynga/scroller

How can I add a click event to each cell for this?  Exact code isn't required just the idea of where to start.  I haven't spent enough time with Canvas yet, but I think this is a good place to start.

I want to be able to get the cell that's clicked and query inside it.  like

```
context.click(function(e) {
  alert(e.hasSpecificAttribute);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with this before, but from the few minutes I just spent with it I think you will have to calculate the cell yourself.

If you run the demos they have (publicly hosted by someone here http://qwan.org/scroller/demo/), you'll notice that the canvas version is different from the DOM-based options. The DOM-based options actually use `div` elements, so you could easily pick out the cell using classes and/or id's. The canvas version seems to use one large canvas, though.

Their demo page displays the current scroll values that are affecting the horizontal and vertical offset. You should be able to just grab those, and combine them with the location that the user clicked within the parent container as well as the width and height of each cell to determine which cell was clicked on. For instance:

```
var x_cell = Math.floor((scroll_x + click_x) / cell_width);
var y_cell = Math.floor((scroll_y + click_y) / cell_height);
```

Note however that this won't really let you query the pixels on the canvas in that cell. Cells in this API seem to be an abstract concept that aren't really part of the structure of the canvas (ie. there aren't many little canvas elements). So, you might then want to use the cell coordinates to determine a region of the canvas that you can use `getImageData()` on. This would be very straightforward, and would just be `context.getImageData(x_cell * cell_width, y_cell * cell_height, cell_width, cell_height);`.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, I will have a deeper look into doing the calc myself.  You are right, this looks lower level, maybe I need to build more on top of it first.